Select incomplete record if all other records are complete
I have a table that contains inspection data.  There are multiple inspections per application.  I'm needing a query to identify applications where all inspections are complete except one specific inspection type.  The types of inspections can vary from application to application. Using the below example, I'd want to select application 2024-1 as only the Final inspection is incomplete.  2024-2 should be excluded as it has the Final & Plumbing incomplete.



Application
Inspection
Status




2024-1
Foundation
complete


2024-1
Framing
complete


2024-1
Final
incomplete


2024-2
Foundation
complete


2024-2
Framing
complete


2024-2
Plumbing
incomplete


2024-2
Final
incomplete



I'm not really sure where to start this type of logic validation and Google has been coming up flat.  I would appreciate some guidance to get this started.
Thanks.

select application from yourtable group by application having count(case when status = 'incomplete' then 1 end) = 1 ?

If you need the entire row, you can join the above bacuse a window function instead of a group-by: SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY Application) AS IncompleteCount FROM InspectionData WHERE Status = 'incomplete') IC WHERE IncompleteCount = 1. See this db<>fiddle for a demo of this and other options.

@siggemannen I suspect the OP also needs to check that count of completes > 0. Your suggestion would also return applications that have one inspection only, which is incomplete.

@JonathanWillcock yeah, you're probably right. Well, it's easy to add another case when to handle that, something like: AND count(case when status = 'complete' then 1 end) > 0

@T N thanks so much that info and examples in db<>fiddle was exactly what I needed to get me towards the result I was looking for.
